# How to mock $_SERVER variables for laravel tests?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm using the shibboleth apache module for federated single sign-on. It sets the `$_SERVER` variable with a user's entitlements from active directory. In my laravel application, I use a custom authentication and user provider which leverages these entitlements for resource authorization.

My simplified user model has something like this:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return Request::server('entitlement') === 'admin';
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to test this because `Request::server` always returns nothing for that value.

```
public function setUp()
{
    $_SERVER['entitlement'] = 'admin';
    parent::setUp();
}

public function test_admin_something()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $response = $this
        ->actingAs($user)
        ->get('/admin/somewhere');

    var_dump($_SERVER['entitlement']);        // string(5) "admin"
    var_dump(Request::server('entitlement')); // NULL

    $response->assertStatus(200); // always fails 403
}
```

I've also tried `setUpBeforeClass` and checked all of the other server variables which appear to be ignored during testing in lieu of a custom crafted Request object. I also cannot mock the Request façade, [per the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mocking#mocking-facades).

Comment: Try changing `->get('/admin/somewhere')` to `->call('GET', '/admin/somewhere', ['entitlement' => 'admin']);`. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#custom-http-requests

Comment: What test suite are you using, and what version.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy phpunit 5.7.20 laravel 5.4.24

Comment: @btl thanks but no dice, that's for passing input data populating `$_GET` and `$_POST` but not `$_SERVER`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Digging into [the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/54e5d218e7eaffa4dbc5760640948f426c9539a0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L27) reveals an undocumented method `withServerVariables`

```
public function test_admin_something()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $response = $this
        ->withServerVariables(['entitlement' => 'admin'])
        ->actingAs($user)
        ->get('/admin/somewhere');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```